# AJAX Post of JavaScript String Array to JsonResult as List<string> Always Returns Null?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, arrays, json

I'm trying to build up a string array in JavaScript and get the results in a string list in the action method.  Below is what my JavaScript looks like.  I'm using jQuery 1.4.2.  The problem is my List in the action method is always showing NULL.  Will a JavaScript string array not map correct to a string list in C#?

```
var test = ['test1', 'test2'];
var parms = {
  var1: 'some string',
  var2: test
};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Test/JSONTestAction",
  async: false,
  data: parms,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

    // success
  }
});
```

Then my JsonResult looks like the following:

```
public JsonResult JSONTestAction(string var1, List <string> var2) {
 // var2 is always NULL -- not good

 return Json(new {
  test = "test"
 });
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I faced the same problem after updating to jquery 1.4.2. You can find the solution [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (in the Ajax section).

Adding traditional : true in the ajax options should work.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    url: "/Test/JSONTestAction",
    async: false,
    data: parms,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

        // success
    }
});
```

Comment: Damn, I've been scratching my head for hour about this one. Thank you!

Comment: The `here` link is broken.

Comment: Thanks @RyanGates, honestly I can´t remember now what was in that link. I believe [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) may help now.

Answer (score 7):

This change was to make native behavior better for PHP/Rails users, [you can read about the params changes more here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

You can enable it per-request like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
 //Stuff...
 traditional:true 
});
```

Or globally like this (only need to run once before firing  any requests):

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

Comment: just FYI its actually: jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

Comment: right on :)  funny because i actually came back to this post as a reference on how to do this globally on a recent project.

Comment: @aherrick it always happens :D