# ASP.NET MVC: How to post an array of textboxes to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to dynamically build a list of textboxes using javascript and jquery. The problem I am having is when the textboxes are posted how do I capture the information in the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steve Sanderson has a blog post with sample code showing precisely how to do this: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Answer (score 5):

Are you doing something like the the [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) example or something different?  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527658/jquery-sortable-toarray-with-asp-net-mvc-actionresult) kinda looks like a similar question as well.

Comment: This is solution seems much better, very worhty of a look.

Comment: Yes, this looks like a better solution to me as well.