# Posting complex data to MVC controllers/actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've already done research on how to post data to MVC controllers/actions and I'm running into a bit of trouble. I wish to post data (via javascript), to my MVC Controller, in this format:

```
{
  someString: "thisString",
  myArray: ["string1", "string2"]
}
```

My MVC Action has the following signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult someAction(FormCollection formValues);
```

If I check the values of formValues, I'll see key/value pairs:

```
key: "someString"
value: "thisString"

key: "myArray[]"
value: [0]: "string1", [1]: "string2"
```

It all looks good untill I try:

```
TryUpdateModel(MyCustomModel);
```

The key/value pair someString/"thisString" binds perfects but the array (myArray) resolves to null.

My Model looks like this:

```
public MyCustomModel 
{
    public string someString {get; set;}
    public string [] myArray {get; set;}
}
```

Here is how my post looks like (jQuery):

```
$.post
(
    "Controller/someAction",
    {
        someString: "thisString",
        myArray: ["string1", "string2"],
    },
    function(data) { ...do something }
);
```

What on earth am I doing wrong? Does the default MVC ModelBinder not support binding a simple array of strings?

Comment: if your on MVC 3, you should try posting as JSON from the JS (including stingify'ing it)

Comment: lol tried that to no avail, unless i did it wrong...but thanks

Comment: No probs, perhaps update your post with the JS your using to post to the action? So we can see all the parts of the flow.

Comment: I've never used @spencerooni's solution.  I have used `$.postify` [here](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/post-complex-javascript-objects-to-asp-net-mvc-controllers/). You'll have to use the tweak in the comments to avoid errors being thrown on null elements, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the following when posting to your controller action

```
traditional: true
```

I just replicated the issue on my machine and that solved it. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form) post which seems to have contained the same solution

**Edit**

Here's [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515773/ajax-post-of-javascript-string-array-to-jsonresult-as-liststring-always-returns)...