# ASP.NET MVC jquery checkboxlist post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arrays, jquery

post methot:

```
function PostChartValues(meter_id, range_type_id, start_date, end_date) {
var values = $("#type_selection").val();
//values = expected values as string array
$.ajax({
    url: '/Widget/GetMeterReadingsTimeSeries',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { MeterType: meter_id, DateRangeType: range_type_id, StartDate: start_date, EndDate: end_date, Parameters: values },
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#chart_loading_div").show();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $("#chart_loading_div").fadeOut();
        $(".grids").jqGrid('GridUnload');
        grid(meter_id, range_type_id, $("#start_date").val(), $("#end_date").val());
    },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#chart").html(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Seçilen kritere uygun veri bulunamadı!");
    }
});   //end ajax
} //end PostChartValues
```

action method:

```
public ActionResult GetMeterReadingsTimeSeries(int MeterType, int DateRangeType, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate,string[] Parameters)
{
    // ...
    return PartialView("_TimeSeries", chart);
}
```

I debugged it. only Parameters array is null. Is there an other way to post array with jquery post?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515773/ajax-post-of-javascript-string-array-to-jsonresult-as-liststring-always-return) so-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can post selected values as string then you parse it back to array. I have created basic sample below,

**Markup**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#someButton').click(function () {
            var selectedValues = [];
            $('#MyDiv input:checked').each(function () {
                selectedValues.push($(this).val());
            });
            console.log(selectedValues);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'someurl',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { values: selectedValues.join(",") }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<button id="someButton">Do Ajax</button>
<div id="MyDiv">
    <input type="checkbox" value="test1" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="test2" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="test3" />
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {       
       public void Test(string values)
        {
            string[] selectedValues = values.Split(',');
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1. "join" and "split" are good idea. Thanks. But I think, there may be a better way.

Comment: Yes it is, you can create form and model then send it to server via ajax, $("#someForm").serialize() gives you post data and you can handle it from controller action.. For sample http://pastebin.com/DVfvR0K7

Comment: Yes. I m allready using your suggestion. But I dont want to break my available scruct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to get the selected values if you're using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
var selectedValues = _.map($("#myDiv:checked"), function (item) { return $(item).val(); });
```